# I want to remove a dict key, pair from my list of dic

Tags: python

I have a dictionary called `total_list`. I want to find the key, value pairs in `total_list` where len(value)==1, and then add it to a new dictionary called `new_dict` and then remove that specific key, value pair from `total_list`. However, when I remove from `total_list`, my `new_dict` also becomes empty for some reason and I'm not really sure why.

```
total_list = {104370544: [31203.7, 1234], 106813775: [187500.0], 106842625: [60349.8]}

new_dict = {}
for k,v in list(total_list.items()):
    if len(v) == 1:
        new_dict[k] = v
        total_list.pop(k)
```

I did some googling and haven't found any solutions.

Comment: Perhaps in the answers to your existing question?

Comment: You have a single dictionary, not a list of dictionaries. A **very** quick google shows that the syntax of `dict.pop` is `dict.pop(key, default_value)`

Comment: Your code as it is does not runs

Comment: actually someone posted a way to do it via two different loops and it work lol idk why they deleted it..

Comment: just change your code to `total_list.pop(k)` and it should work

Comment: The code as it is  runs fine

Comment: @SyntaxVoid the default_value in pop is not a mandatory param

Comment: @Optimus My comment was to point out that the OP is using square brackets `[]` instead of parenthesis `()`

Comment: @SysntaxVoid Oh ok Since i had submitted an edit for the question with right syntax, misunderstood your intent.

Answer (score 0):

```
new_dict[k] = v
```

You insert the reference as value, but not the value. Thus if you remove `.pop` the key:value pair the inserted reference points to nothing.

```
new_dict[k] = v[:]
```

Now you obtain the value from start to end position and not the reference anymore.

Comment: This is untrue. At least in my python version. Here's a small example: `x = [1,2,3]; y = {0: x}; y.pop(0); print(x)` (x still exists!). Or also: `x = [1,2,3]; y = {0: x}; del x; print(y)` (the dictionary still has a reference to x!!). Why? `del` lowers the reference count of the object but doesn't necessarily delete it unless all references are removed. In both examples, there is still a reference after the "removal".

Answer (score 0):

First, the variable names are a little misleading. The first dictionary is not list at all (the title is also misleading). Try to pick variable names that are short and descriptive.

Second, you should be using `()` when you call `dict.pop` but I think that's a typo when you were making this question.

Lastly, since `pop` returns the value, you can store it in your `new_dict` in one line.

```py
total_list = {104370544: [31203.7, 1234], 106813775: [187500.0], 106842625: [60349.8]}

new_dict = {}
for k,v in list(total_list.items()):
    if len(v) == 1:
        new_dict[k] = total_list.pop(k)

print(total_list)
print(new_dict)
```

Or a one-liner of the above:

```py
new_dict = {k: total_list.pop(k) for k,v in list(total_list.items()) if len(v) == 1}
```

Output:

```
{104370544: [31203.7, 1234]}
{106813775: [187500.0], 106842625: [60349.8]}
```